# didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken is not called up in ios 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, objective-c-blocks

I have to implement **APNS** in my project, I have created **APNS** **SSL** in developer portal, and using this i have created new provision profile for this.
Using SSL certificate I created **P12** file then merging it to **PEM** file.
I get popup that App would like to send you notification.....
i accept that but still i didn't get the device token !!

In `didfinishLaunching` i use this part

```
float ver = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];

   if(ver >= 8 && ver<9)
    {
        if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)])
        {
           [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];

            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];

            //[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];

        }
    }else if (ver >=9){

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];

    }
    else{
        //iOS6 and iOS7 specific code
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge|UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert];
    }


I have used delegate method of push notification 


- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError*)error
{
    NSLog(@"Failed to get token, error: %@", error);
}


- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

    for (id key in userInfo) {
        NSLog(@"key: %@, value: %@", key, [userInfo objectForKey:key]);
    }    

}
```

Comment: are you installing build using APNS certificate in device ?

Comment: yes with apns certificate i have created provision profile and using that build , i use ipa file

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try with this one.

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0){

    UIUserNotificationType types = UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
    UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert;

    UIUserNotificationSettings *mySettings =
    [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:nil];

    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:mySettings];
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];


}else{
    [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert)];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you forget your  didRegisterUserNotificationSettings method so:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings {
    if (notificationSettings.types != UIUserNotificationTypeNone) {
        NSLog(@"didRegisterUser is called");
        [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
    }
}
```

at the same place check the following scenario also.

- try in another device once

Comment: i have added that but still not getting device token

Answer (score 1):

in ios 9 you need to required only `if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
    }`

an other changes is

1. select Project->General set **team**
2. go capabilities and turn **on** Push notification.
   [image]