# Device token getting Nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, apple-push-notifications, ios9

I have a strange issue, Some of my users are returning blank (or null) device tokens for `Apple Push Notification`. It happening only some of user's only not for all user's,

*Here's my code,*

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {

   #if !TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR

       [_globalKRData setPreferences:deviceToken withKey:kPushToken]; // Preferences 

       PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
       [currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:deviceToken];
currentInstallation.channels = @[@"global"];
       [currentInstallation saveInBackground];

    #endif

}
```

Is it possible if device is `Jail break` that's why i getting nil device token ?

**Update**

For example First time user allowing push notification and it works properly,

Now user go to setting and disable the notification from setting's

[image: Disable notification]

Then after it i will not get device token **that was fine but problem is** now user uninstall the app,

Then after Download the app again then after `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` not called so i getting nil device token and when i check setting it will showing notification on

Comment: No, they simply may not have granted the permission.

Comment: @HarikrishnanT so it means if the device is jail break then device token not generated right ?

Comment: If you need the device token, the user must provide permission to receive push notification. If they deny the permission, the device token will not be received. And when you try to access it from the defaultPreferances, it will return null

Comment: @HarikrishnanT yes i know this thing but user may have set ON the notification but not getting the device token

Comment: you have provisional certificate in configure push notification?

Comment: @Rohitsuvagiya yes its works properly this issue regarding Some of my users are returning blank (or null) not all ..

Comment: @Mayank Patel please check internet connection at the time getting the device token , this also will be the reason

Comment: No, look at the code - it's saving in an asynchronous background service

Comment: @MayankPatel did the method "didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken" gets a call or not??

Comment: Post a picture of your Installation table from Parse ?

Comment: @jesses.co.tt i have updated question check it

Comment: @satheesh internet connection working perfectly check my updated question

Comment: So... why is any of that confusing? Wouldn't you expect to get a nil token in that case ?

Comment: @jesses.co.tt when i uninstall the app during notification is disable from setting now reinstall the app again and checking notification is on but didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken this method is not called

Comment: Seems there are a few other SO posts about it not being called on iOS 9.. Eg.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33541229/didregisterforremotenotificationswithdevicetoken-is-not-called-up-in-ios-9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **iOS8** I have deleted my app before that i turn **OFF** the notification,then i run my application did register is not called,then i again go to the settings and find that **Allow notification** is **ON**, but the "**didRegisterForRemoteNotification"** didn't get a call,

Then I turn "**Allow notification**" to **OFF** and again i turn it **ON**, then i come to my app I found the device token, But its working fine after that, but user have to turn it off by manually and again he has to turn it on, `of course its a bug of apple`,

It will work fine in **iOS 9**