# didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken not being called in ios 9.3.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, remote-notifications, ios9.3.1

I am implementing remote notifications in one of my applications and for getting the device token i am using the method.

```
  - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    NSLog(@"Did Register for Remote Notifications with Device Token (%@)", deviceToken);
    NSString * token = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", deviceToken];
    //Format token as you need:
    token = [token stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    token = [token stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""];
    token = [token stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@""];

   // [OTWebServiceHelper sharedInstance].deviceTocken    = token;
    NSLog(@"App Token for Device%@",token);
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:token forKey:@"MyAppDeviceToken"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

}
```

It works fine when i am checking the 8.0 devices but in ios 9.3.1 it is not getting called.

I referred this link but of no use.

[didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken is not called up in ios 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33541229/didregisterforremotenotificationswithdevicetoken-is-not-called-up-in-ios-9)

Please help me.

For registering i am using the code:

```
  -(void)registerForPUSHNotifications {

    NSString *iOSversion = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
    NSString *prefix = [[iOSversion componentsSeparatedByString:@"."] firstObject];
    float versionVal = [prefix floatValue];


    if (versionVal >= 8)
    {
        //for iOS8
        UIUserNotificationSettings *settings =
        [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert |
         UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
         UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
    }
    else
    {

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];

    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to include the code you use to register.  How you handle the registration is irrelevant.

Comment: @Avi please see the register code

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 Thanks. Will it effect if even we are debugging in iPhone 6 with 9.3.1 with development certificates for Push and debugging?

Comment: @AshleyRodrigues check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/38456437/4601170 ...